# What's asking for all of these images?

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I've inherited a large project and while investigating some performance issues I've noticed that the site downloads a whole bunch of images without ever using them, causing massive delays.  Using Firebug or Chrome, is there any way to see where in the code it's actually asking for these images?  I've trying stepping through some Javascript that might be the culprit but this process is tedious.

Comment: Chrome, Network tab, Initiator column is worth a look (filter by images @ the bottom)

Comment: first disable javascript and see if the images are still loading. if not, then check the source code. If the images still load then you have to go through the html / server side language

Comment: Looks like it's definitely somewhere in Javascript.  Hmm, the initiator column says it's somewhere in jQuery (line 6301 of 1.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few css image preloaders that parse the css then preload all images.

See if you have a library included that may do that